# Python extract partial infos from file

Tags: python, parsing, readfile

I was wondering how I can extract partial infos of an nfo file.  What i need is the tracklist.  The file is an nfo file.

```
Encoder    : Flac 1.2.1

[Track List]

1.  The Chronic (Intro) (Feat. Snoop Doggy Dog)     1:57
2.  Fuck Wit Dre Day (And Everybody's Celebratini')  4:52
(Feat. Snoop Doggy Dog, RBX & Jewell)
3.  Let Me Ride (Feat. Snoop Doggy Dog, Ruben &     4:21
Jewell)
4.  The Day The Niggaz Took Over (Feat. Snoop       4:33
Doggy Dog, RBX & Dat Nigga Daz)
5.  Nuthin' But A "G" Thang (Feat. Snoop Doggy      3:58
Dog)
6.  Deeez Nuuuts (Feat. Snoop Doggy Dog)            5:06
7.  Lil' Ghetto Boy (Feat. Snoop Doggy Dog, Dat     5:29
Nigga Daz & Nate Dogg)

This is the 2009 Remastered.....
```

How can i get only the part from [Track List]  to Dogg) without anything else?

```
<td align='left' colspan='2'>Artist: Dr. Dre<br />
Album: The Chronic: Re-Lit &amp; From The Vault<br />
Label: WIDEawake/Death Row<br />
Genre: Hip-Hop<br />
Bitrate: 983 kbps avg<br />
Source: CD<br />
Playtime: 01:02:52 (444.MB)<br />
Rls date: 2011-10-06<br />
Store date: 2009-09-01<br />
Encoder: Flac 1.2.1 [Track List]<br />
1. The Chronic (Intro) (Feat. Snoop Doggy Dog) 1:57<br >
2. Fuck Wit Dre Day (And Everybody&#039;s          Celebratin&#039;) 4:52<br />
(Feat. Snoop Doggy Dog, RBX &amp; Jewell)<br />
3. Let Me Ride (Feat. Snoop Doggy Dog, Ruben &amp;    4:21<br />
Jewell)<br />
4. The Day The Niggaz Took Over (Feat. Snoop 4:33<br />
Doggy Dog, RBX &amp; Dat Nigga Daz)<br />
5. Nuthin&#039; But A &quot;G&quot; Thang (Feat. Snoop Doggy 3:58<br />
Dog)<br />
6. Deeez Nuuuts (Feat. Snoop Doggy Dog) 5:06<br />

This is the 2009 Remastered Edition of this classic    album</td>
                    </tr></table></div><br/><br/>
```

Comment: NFO has no official format, so you have to write your own parser. But you most likely to get unhappy, since your parser will not work for other nfo files, because the author can put in whatever he wants. nfo (info) ist just a textfile.

Comment: Actually it can also be from an html file..

Comment: Well It can... but i can also be anything else. I mean there's no definition (RFC) for nfo files. Is it a html file in your case? If so, you may post the right example snipped.

Comment: Edited with html example

Comment: aww... the full text is in the `<td>` tag, so parsing it as html does not make any sence. if the track-title may wrapped with a `div` or `span`, you were able to get the data using `lxml`. But this html file is useless for your goal. You may start using regex to get what you want from the nfo. Start with: take every line starting with a number.

Comment: Nice idea..  So if line.startswith 0* 1*, print line..  Might be correct?

Comment: I'm with Mathias: Read the file line by line, start parsing at the line that contains `[Track List]` and start looking for lines that start with a number and their following lines without a number to complete the title. Stop parsing on empty line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you an overall idea what might help:

```py
text = """Encoder    : Flac 1.2.1

[Track List]

1.  The Chronic (Intro) (Feat. Snoop Doggy Dog)     1:57
2.  Fuck Wit Dre Day (And Everybody's Celebratini')  4:52
(Feat. Snoop Doggy Dog, RBX & Jewell)
3.  Let Me Ride (Feat. Snoop Doggy Dog, Ruben &     4:21
Jewell)
4.  The Day The Niggaz Took Over (Feat. Snoop       4:33
Doggy Dog, RBX & Dat Nigga Daz)
5.  Nuthin' But A "G" Thang (Feat. Snoop Doggy      3:58
Dog)
6.  Deeez Nuuuts (Feat. Snoop Doggy Dog)            5:06
7.  Lil' Ghetto Boy (Feat. Snoop Doggy Dog, Dat     5:29
Nigga Daz & Nate Dogg)

This is the 2009 Remastered..... """

import re

tracks = []
parse = False
starttoken = "[Track List]"

for line in text.split('\n'):
    if starttoken in line:
        parse = True
        continue
    if not parse:
        continue

    m = re.match('(\d+)\.\s+(.*?)\s+(\d+:\d+)', line.strip())

    if m:
        tracks.append(list(m.groups()))
    elif line:
        tracks[-1][1] += ' ' + line
    elif tracks:
        break

for track in tracks:
    print("{:>02}) {} ({})".format(*track))
```

Output:

```
01) The Chronic (Intro) (Feat. Snoop Doggy Dog) (1:57)
02) Fuck Wit Dre Day (And Everybody's Celebratini') (Feat. Snoop Doggy Dog, RBX & Jewell) (4:52)
03) Let Me Ride (Feat. Snoop Doggy Dog, Ruben & Jewell) (4:21)
04) The Day The Niggaz Took Over (Feat. Snoop Doggy Dog, RBX & Dat Nigga Daz) (4:33)
05) Nuthin' But A "G" Thang (Feat. Snoop Doggy Dog) (3:58)
06) Deeez Nuuuts (Feat. Snoop Doggy Dog) (5:06)
07) Lil' Ghetto Boy (Feat. Snoop Doggy Dog, Dat Nigga Daz & Nate Dogg) (5:29)
```

It may overcomplicate things a little, but I'm not sure what information you need. But you get the idea and can modify it to your needs.

Comment: Nice,  will def try this..  Gonna change it a bit cause files will always be different..  Thanks!